# Java - Asynchronous server/client method?

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous

I'm trying to build an asynchronous server/client task with Java (Beginner).  I have done this in C#, with functions such as Socket.BeginReceive and Socket.BeginAccept to do this, but I'm wondering if there is anything similar for Java?  Or do I have to stick with using threads?

Comment: Look at netty project and or Apache Mina

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`java.nio.channels.AsychronousSocketChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html) and friends.